# UIImagePickerController.frame is not full screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm initializing an **UIImagePickerController** like this:

```
    self.cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    self.cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
    self.cameraController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.cameraController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.cameraController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

The problem is that when this is shown, instead of the camera controls,
I get a black bar in its place.

How can I make **UIImagePickerController.frame** take all the screen space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPhone's camera has a 4:3 aspect ratio whereas the iPhone's screen's aspect ratio is 3:2. Therefore, the live camera picture does not cover the entire screen. If you want to get rid of the black bars, you have to apply a small scaling transform (e.g. 110%) to the camera view.

Comment: Rather than hard-coding a specific scale factor, use the ratio of the ratios. (screen aspect ratio) / (picture aspect ratio) = scale factor to scale the 4:3 camera image up to fit the 3:2 screen. (Don't hard-code the photo or screen aspect ratios either, of course—get the image's and the screen's sizes, and divide width by height for each of them.)

Answer (score 1):

Ole is spot on, figure out that aspect ratio conversion.  Here is the line of code you are probably going to want to implement it.

```
self.cameraController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2, 2);
```